# Proc SQL Update

Tags: sql, sas

How do I update a field using PROC SQL while joining to another table in order to define the criteria? I don't want to update the field with a another field from the second table, I just want to update the field with the word "Small". I'm using this syntax, but it's not working:

```
PROC SQL;
UPDATE GROUP A
SET SEGMENT = 
(SELECT 'SMALL'
 FROM SMALL_GROUP_REPORT B
 WHERE  A.NUMBER = B.NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to update the table with a column from the other table, then you wouldn't want single quotes:

```
PROC SQL;
    UPDATE GROUP A
        SET SEGMENT = (SELECT SMALL
                       FROM SMALL_GROUP_REPORT B
                       WHERE A.NUMBER = B.NUMBER
                      );
```

But you seem to wan the segment to be `'SMALL'`, when the row exists in the other table:

```
PROC SQL;
    UPDATE GROUP A
        SET SEGMENT = 'SMALL'
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM SMALL_GROUP_REPORT B
                      WHERE A.NUMBER = B.NUMBER
                     );
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about EXISTS. What is the SELECT 1 for?

Comment: @JasonSmith It's just dummy data. The EXISTS clause is true if there is 1 or more rows returned.

Comment: Trying the second query; been running about 10 minutes now, which is odd because if I join the two tables together on the same criteria, using a regular SELECT statement, it runs in just a few seconds.

Comment: @JasonSmith . . . An index on `SMALL_GROUP_REPORT(NUMBER)` should help.